# How to style a particular Column Header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sorting, datagrid

I have 5 columns Table, ScanCount , Logical Reads etc.
This is my sorting handler for all columns:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True"
                      Background="White"
                      Foreground="Black">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <EventSetter Event="Click"
                     Handler="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler"/>
    </Style>        
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="GridView1"                   
      ItemsSource="{Binding listAggregation}"
      CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="0,65,0,46" AllowDrop="True" Drop="Grid_Drop" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Table">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
                        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" 
                             Handler="DataGridHeader_PreviewMouseMove"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>


        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

    </DataGrid>

    <Label x:Name="MyGroupDescriptionsList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" 
           AllowDrop="True" Drop="Label_Drop" Background="#FFE2D8D8" Height="31"  QueryContinueDrag="Label_QueryContinueDrag" PreviewMouseMove="Label_Mousemove" Content="Drag Your Header Here" FontWeight="Bold"/>
</Grid>
```

How can i merge both ?? I just want the column header 'Table'(which is the first column) to be able use this drag-drop and rest all columns to use the sorting. Columns are created in code behind.
Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can used **`BasedOn`** to inherit default style. But for that to work instead of setting default style explicitly to **`ColumnHeaderStyle`**, declare it under DataGrid resources section.
After that you can used BasedOn to inherit default style.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumn="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <EventSetter Event="Click"
                         Handler="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Table">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader"
                       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" 
                                 Handler="DataGridHeader_PreviewMouseMove"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        .........
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Rohit-but this adds a new column named 'Table' before an already existing one

Comment: Yeah you have to set `AutoGenerateColumns = False` on dataGrid for that.

Comment: if i set this as false, then only one empty column gets shown on the datagrid 'Table'. All the columns are generated from code behind.

Comment: I didn't get this. In question you mentioned you just need to post these two styles, for which I have provided an answer. What's issue you are getting in generating columns?

Comment: When i set AutoGenerateColumns = False, then all the cloumns gets disappeared except for the one 'Table' on which the PreviewMouseMove event has been set.

Comment: Rohit- i have edited the above to complete xaml.
Thanks for the help!