# DataGrid Columnheader Style - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Created two separate `Datagrids`; one without `columnheader style` and another one with `columnheader style`

***DataGrid 1:***

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PrintReport" ItemsSource="{Binding MonthlyResults}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="12" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"  AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"  AlternationCount="1" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell" >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pattern" Binding="{Binding }"   >
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
          <Style>
             <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
             <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
          </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
      </DataGridTextColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lease" Binding="{Binding VOD,StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}"  >
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
           <Style>
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
          </Style>
       </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
     </DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```

***DataGrid 2:***

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="PrintReport2" ItemsSource="{Binding MonthlyResults}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="13" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"  AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"  AlternationCount="1" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell">  

<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Req - OAR" Binding="{Binding }"   >
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>


     <Style>
     <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
       </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>

    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCyan"/>
        </Style>
                                                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Basic difference being the `DATAGRID 2` column headers have "`background color`" applied to them. The display that I get looks something like this:

[image]

Datagrid2 clumn header shows "extra blank space" below the column header?? How do I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the HeaderStyle. Just use the [default style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066(v=vs.95).aspx) and adjust other parts too:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCyan"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
      <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="#FFC9CACA" />
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4" />
  </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Note that regarding the extra space, the effective part is the *Padding*.

**Edit**
note that You can used *BasedOn* to inherit default style. However, for that to work, you should declare it under *DataGrid* resources section. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313537/how-to-style-a-particular-column-header).